# Is there any easy way to get Ubuntu back after reinstalling windows 8?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, bootloader, mbr

Apparently I can't use the grub> root(hd...) trick from a LiveCD because GRUB can't find itself.

It is on `/dev/hdb5`. There are 3 hard-drives. One has Windows 8 and Ubuntu 13, one has Ubuntu 12, and the other is just data.

Also GRUB which is not by default part of the Try-Ubuntu13 DVD when `apt-get` did has no auto-complete so I can't figure out what grub thinks the drive layout is anyway.

Is that the end of my Ubuntu 13 - should I just reinstall Ubuntu because I can't boot into linux anymore?

Answer (score 3):

*Answer written by the OP in [one edit](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/334724/2):*

> After hours of GRUB trouble, this these lines solved it in seconds:
>
> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
> ```

Answer (score 0):

1. Make bootable usb with supergrub or burn it on cd.
2. Start Ubuntu with supergrub (Boot => Detect Any Os => Select your Ubuntu boot option).
3. Once you have Ubuntu running install Synaptic package manager from the software center.
4. Open Synaptic and search grub from the installed packages.
5. Mark for reinstallation all packages that contain grub or grub2 (I don't remember which package was exactly, so I mark most of them).
6. Reboot and grub should load.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
UEFI only

1. If Windows 8 still loading, enter in your UEFI BIOS boot options and select Ubuntu boot option.

It works fine for me.

PS: Don't try boot Windows 8 from the grub menu, it won't boot. If you want to boot Winows 8 just open your BIOS boot menu (Example: For ASUS motherboards boot menu press ESC) and select Windows 8.